# import c++ dll to windows phone project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, dllimport

I'm new on windows phone developement and i have one problem that i don't know how to resolve....

the problem is....

i have a c++ project that i had complided with visual c++ 2010 and this create one dll with code compiled...

so i know that C# import dll libraries but when i add refrences it's make this error "Unable to retrieve assembly fullname ""Parameter name: AssemblyPath" and i dont kown what it means...

I searched on google and i found one method to import c++ dll manualy with DllImport and calling a external method... that causes one error because it's dont find the dll location... it's happens because wp7 don't suport C++???

thanks for help me

Answer (score 2):

Neither P/Invoke nor C++/CLI is supported, only managed user code. See [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/096b66ee-23c1-47b7-a768-bc2ae9e94c7c).

Answer (score 1):

3rd party WP7 apps may only comprise of managed code. C++ is also not a supported language, even in managed form, at this time.

Answer (score 0):

WP7 doesn't support c++.  you would also probably need to recompile the c++ dll anyways, even if it was supported.

Comment: I don't think it'll ever support C++. If, it will support C++/CLI as this is managed, but unmanaged code? I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah pure speculation on my part.  I am probably confusing a lot of people.